# how to calculate $E(X+Y|X<x,Y<y)$

Tags: random-variables, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, density-function

consider $X\sim U(0,1), Y\sim U(0,1-x))$
for $E(X+Y|X<x,Y<y)$ I'd consider $E(X|X<x,Y<y)+E(Y|X<x,Y<y)$
$f_{x,y} = f_{y|x}f_x = 1/(1-x)$

$E(X|X<x,Y<y) = E(X|X<x) = \int_0^x xdx = x^2/2$

$E(Y|X<x,Y<y) = \int_0^{y}\int_0^{x}y/(1-x)dxdy = \int_0^{x}1/(1-x)dx\int_0^{y}ydy = \frac{-\ln(1-x)y^2}{2}$

Why is this logic wrong?

Comment: You can not write $E(X|X<x,Y<y) = E(X|X<x)$, since $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: @SumanChakraborty  but when integrating, how do you ensure the upper bound of dy is below 1-x and y?

Comment: Don't use $x,y$ as the bound variables, when you have them in the conditions.  Integrate with bound variables of $s,t$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp please elaborate, I'm very lost

Comment: $X\sim U(0,1), Y\sim U(0,1-x))$ should be $X\sim U(0,1)$, $Y \mid X=x \sim U(0,1-x))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use $x,y$ as the bound variables, when you have them in the conditions.  Integrate with bound variables of $s,t$ to avoid confusion.

$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X+Y\mid X<x,Y<y) &= \mathsf E((X+Y)\mathbf 1_{X<x,Y<y})/\mathsf P(X<x,Y<y)\\  &=\dfrac{\int_{0}^{x}\int_0^{\min\{y,1-s\}}(s+t)/(1-s)\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d s}{\int_{0}^{x}\int_0^{\min\{y,1-s\}}1/(1-s)\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d s}\end{align}$

Comment: how would you integrate on a bound that is not set, suppose both X and Y are <0.5, what does integrating to min(0.5,1-s) mean?

Comment: It means in the case of $0<1-y<x<1$ you integrate over the domain: $$\{\langle s,t\rangle:0<s<1-y, 0<t<y\}\cup\{\langle s,t\rangle:1-y<s<x, 0<t<1-s\}$$  And ... similarly in the other cases.